# Database operations on DataGrid by Entity Framework - MVVM/WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

In my program users can create invoices. I want the user's actions to be reflected in the database immediately when change the cell.

- User firstly enters barcode data. When this property/cell changed, EF searches to find the product from '`Product`' table with this barcode. If there is data, the product attributes will be fetched to cell. (ProductName, UnitPrice and others...) At this moment, the row must be saved in the `RowBills` table. When change any cell on the row, it should also change in the database too. If there is no product with entered barcode value, a window opens to create product. (to **Product** table)

Create Invoice View:

[image: Create Invoice View]

As far as I researched, I should use CollectionChanged handler. I tried it but didn't get what I wanted.

**CreateInvoiceView.xaml**

```
                <DataGrid x:Name="RowBillsGrid" Grid.Row="1" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#FF788697" AlternationCount = "2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RowBillList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Barkod" Binding="{Binding Barcode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="2*" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ürün Açıklaması" Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Width="4*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adet" Binding="{Binding Quantity}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISK" Binding="{Binding DiscountPerc}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="KDV" Binding="{Binding Tax}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birim Fiyat" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tutar" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**CreateInvoiceViewModel**

```
private readonly CalcuTraderDbContextFactory _contextFactory = new CalcuTraderDbContextFactory();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private ObservableCollection<RowBill> _rowBillList;
    public ObservableCollection<RowBill> RowBillList
    {
        get { return _rowBillList; }
        set
        {
            _rowBillList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RowBillList");
        }
    }

        public CreateInvoiceViewModel()
        {
        using (CalcuTraderDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var titles = context.CurrentAccounts.ToList();
            CurrentAccountList = new ObservableCollection<CurrentAccount>(titles);
        }
                 
        RowBillList = new ObservableCollection<RowBill>();
        RowBillList.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;

    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this block runs one time when click the any cell (not on change)
    }

    private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I wrote all properties with OnPropertyChange in CreateInvoiceViewModel.

```
        private string _barcode;
    public string Barcode
    {
        get
        {
            return _barcode;
        }
        set
        {
            _barcode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Barcode));
        }
    }

    private string _productName;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get
        {
            return _productName;
        }
        set
        {
            _productName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProductName));
        }
    }
.
.
. 
and others...
```

What i want to do

- When row changes, datas will changes at database same time. (Insert and update) When row deletes, record in database will be deleted too. (Delete)
- If there is a product with a barcode entered, product attributes will be fetched row's cell.

Thanks for all replies. Have a nice day.

Comment: No validation? They can stop anywhere they like part way through something and that's OK? Doesn't seem like a good plan to me.

Comment: What do you mean by validation @Andy what is your suggestion? Thanks for reply

Comment: Validating your data before you commit updates is industry standard. YYou can't validate data they haven't entered so you'll becwriting rows with empty columns hoping they input the rest OK.